# Same type to Multiple typescript variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I'm getting a data in my react component props which is all of same type but different variables.

Is there any way so I can just need to define all the type variable in one line.

```
interface IcarouselProps {
  img1: string
  img2: string
  img3: string
  img4: string
  img5: string
  img6: string
  heading1: string,
  heading2: string,
  heading3: string,
  heading4: string,
  heading5: string,
  heading6: string,
}
```

Comment: You can do this: `[key: string]: string` if you just want a dictionary, but it won't assure you that you have keys in the form of img{x} and header{x}

Answer (score 1):

On TS4.1 and above you can write:

```
type IcarouselProps = Record<`${'img' | 'heading'}${number}`, string>;
```

But this will allow accessing properties not in range (1..6) too. So to make type-checking more stricter, you can do something like this:

```
type Enumerate<N extends number, Result extends Array<unknown> = []> = Result['length'] extends N
  ? Result[number]
  : Enumerate<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>;

type IcarouselProps = Record<`${'img' | 'heading'}${Exclude<Enumerate<7>, 0>}`, string>;

// the above will work for any value <46 in place of 7 in TS4.1-4 and <1000 in TS4.5

// `Exclude<Enumerate<TO>, Enumerate<FROM>>` will generate integer range from `FROM` to `TO - 1` both inclusive.
```

Run this on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgxgQwE4HsCuBnCAbACqsDAGRRSygF4oAlCOFJAEwB4ADAEgG8ByASwFsA5tygAfKNwAWEBI14A7YQF8u8tPwBGEJEtYAaKBmBIFggHwBuAFBXQkKAFE1-bQmARmAOSgQAHu-lGDChnLSQDWgw0bGAffwhA4IBBJCQEEGY0eQBreRQAd3kzSigAbQBdYqpI6OBS7mwEwWBJbnK4gKCoTysoKAB+GggomNLQ7XLeqAAuR2dXdy8DUoA6NZqYiOHa+sbFFrbK61twaHhkdCw8AmDqugYWDh4BYTEJaVlTbhVOB184bBoRgeJzqBYeADsZgMAAYzLoDEYTIpLFYgA).